# SAILS JS 1.0 model callback lifecycle is not called

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, sails-mongo

well, I'm trying to create a user with Sails 1.0.0-42, the problem is that the callback lifecycle of the user model is not called. I have tried in many ways and nothing is called. Thanks in advance.

this is the code of Action2 "signup":

```
module.exports = {

   friendlyName: 'Create User',

   description: 'user create action2',

   inputs: {

        name: {
            description: 'user create',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            description: 'user create',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            description: 'user create',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

   },

   exits: {
      notFound: {
        description: 'ERRO create user.',
        responseType: 'notFound'
      }
   },

   fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

        const {name, email, password} = inputs;

        var user = await User.create({name, email, password}).fetch();

        if(!user) return exits.notFound();

        return exits.success(user);

   }
};
```

this is the user model code

```
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.export = {

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },

        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },

        password: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 6,
            required: true,
            columnName: 'hashed_password'
        },

    },

    // Lifecycle Callbacks

    beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {

        // Hash password
        bcrypt.hash(values.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) return cb(err);
            values.password = hash;
            cb();
        });
    }

};
```

the user is created, but the password is not encrypted, and in the tests the beforeCreate is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model file declares:

```
module.export
```

But it needs to be:

```
module.exports
```

That `s` makes a big difference!

The reason it works at all with your current code is that, by default, the built-in `sails-disk` database is *schemaless*, so even though your `User.js` file wasn't exporting anything, it still lets you create records with whatever fields you want.